# Livewire Select field selected

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a select field with values from a table that I would like to compare with another table and mark as selected if a value matches.

```
<select name="tour" class="form-control form-control-sm" wire:model="selectTour">
  @foreach($touren as $tour)
   <option {{ $beleg->Tour == $tour->Gruppe ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $tour->Gruppe }}">{{ $tour->Gruppe }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

If I now reload the page, the matching value is briefly marked as selected, but automatically jumps back to “Please select”.

If I remove wire:model=“selectTour” it works. But can’t perform any actions with the select field.

Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectTour` value in the livewire component is still null or empty (whatever you have set). You need to update that value. Or set the value in mount() like this `$this->selectTour = $this->beleg->Tour` if you have access to beleg in the livewire component.